# VLOOKUP or INDEX+MATCH

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

I have an array of values:

```
  A      B              C
1 TypeID MaterialTypeID Quantity
2 18     34             256
3 18     35             512
4 20     34             386
5 20     36             773
```

Now I need a formula where I can search for lets say `TypeID=20` and `MaterialTypeID=34` and the formula gives me the `Quantity=386`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution:

```
=INDEX(C:C;MATCH(D6&D7;A:A&B:B;0))
```

where `D6` and `D7` are my search criteria...

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be another, maybe easier, way to do it:

```
=QUERY(A2:C5, "SELECT C WHERE A=20 AND B=34")
```